# How to define a "global variable" from an "ansible-playbook extra variable" in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, global-variables

I'm using Ansible 2.1.1.0. In Ansible, is there a way to define a variable in **group_vars/all** file with a dynamic variable set as an extra var in ansible-playbook command?

I have my play.sh file as follows.

```
ansible-playbook site.yml -i hosts -e "home_dir=$1"
```

Then I want to use it as a global variable in group_vars/all file as follows.

```
my_dir: {{ home_dir }}/sub_dir/my_dir
```

I know the syntax above is wrong for the **all file**, and this can be done by using the variable directly in the task yaml file. Is there any way I can use a dynamic '*ansible-playbook extra variable*' for defining a '*global variable*'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about *global_vars* existence in Ansible...

If you want to make `my_dir` available to all hosts, you can define group variable for a special group `all` like:

file `./group_vars/all`:

```
my_dir: "{{ home_dir }}/sub_dir/my_dir"
```

This way `my_dir` will be constructed based on `home_dir` extra variable and be available as group variable for all hosts.

Comment: Yeah sorry. My bad. It should be "group_vars"; plus, yep the double quotes does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it wothout creating a directory? I'd like to use ansible includes... I don't like creating directories for a single config file

Comment: Yes, define `my_dir` inside your main inventory file for group `all`.